# Laravel auth routes with fallback route

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel

I'm building a laravel app with frontend in react and admin panel in simple html. I'm having problem with accessing other pages because of fallback route(ReactJS does it's own routing). Now if I try going to `/login` the login page flashes and redirects to react app.

`routes/web.php`

```
Auth::routes();
Route::fallback(function() {
   return view('welcome');
});
```

How would I make defined routes available and only return welcome view if no other route is matched?

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. Layout file was using main div with id "app" which was overriden by react.